# Rounding Issue with Elasticsearch

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch

I'm trying to round up to 2 decimal places in Elasticsearch aggregations but I've not been able to do so...am using Groovy as my scripting engine.

```
...
"aggs": {
        "avg_response_time": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "exec_time",
            "script": "_value.round(2)"
          }
        },
...
```

Any help ?

Comment: so what is the exact problem?  error?  exception? ...

Comment: this might work. `new BigDecimal(_value).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP)`

Comment: @cfrick, the rounding doesn't seems to work, I get the original decimal number back. I tried your suggestion but I get an error mesage: java.lang.SecurityException: Expression [ConstructorCallExpression] is not allowed: new java.math.BigDecimal(_value)

Comment: Why not round it on the client side? Forcing a script to do it per-value is going to cost a lot more than doing it to the result.

Comment: @pickypg, I've got lots of result...looping the results on the client side will not be efficient as well.